# Need to access with community management API

Tags: linkedin-api

I had requested access to Linkedin Community Management APIs. It got rejected due to "Identity vetting failed" (ss attached)(https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q6Jy0.png). Not getting answers on how to proceed. Pls help.

We wanted access to these apis, got request rejected

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.